# Tabs in Android disappears. Code was working before but now it stopped working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent

I have used Tab Control and `RecyclerView` together in Android. The way it functions is I have `SearchBar` in the `toolbar`. When the user enters the search query in the search bar. Upon hitting the search button, `tab's` Fragments are supposed to be loaded with data. Issues are as follows.

1) Tabs icon disappear

2) When debugging through the code found (Since I am using ViewPager with Tab Layout to implement Tabs in android) that getItem method of PagerAdapter class is called twice every time getItem is triggered.

I am stuck and don't know what to do. Not much help online as well.

1) Tab initialization Code:-

```
 private TabLayout tabLayout;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tablayout);

 tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.mipmap.craigslist_new1));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.mipmap.kijiji_new1));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.mipmap.letgo_new1));        
 tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.mipmap.varagesale_new1));        
 tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.mipmap.facebook_new1));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

}


 @Override
 public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

    //loadRecyclerViewData(query);

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("searchText", query);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PageAdapter adapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount(), bundle);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

2) PagerAdapter:-

```
 public class PageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

      int mNoofTabs;
      Bundle bundle;

      public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, int NumberOfTabs, Bundle bundle)
        {
        super(fragmentManager);
        this.mNoofTabs = NumberOfTabs;
        this.bundle = bundle;

    }
     @Override
     public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch(i)
         {
            case 0 :
                CraigslistFragment tab1 = new CraigslistFragment();
                tab1.setArguments(bundle);
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                KijijiFragment tab2 = new KijijiFragment();
                tab2.setArguments(bundle);
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                letgoFragment tab3 = new letgoFragment();
                tab3.setArguments(bundle);
                return tab3;
            case 3:
                VaragesaleFragment tab4 = new VaragesaleFragment();
                tab4.setArguments(bundle);
                return tab4;
            case 4:
                FacebookFragment tab5 = new FacebookFragment();
                tab5.setArguments(bundle);
                return tab5;

            default:
                return null;
        }

     }

     @Override
     public int getCount() {
        return mNoofTabs;
     }
}
```

Comment: refer this link https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/